# Browsers changing <input> value!

Tags: forms, post, encoding

So, I have a very simple form:

```
<form action="AJAXemail.php" id='email_form' method="POST" target="_blank" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
<p> 
<label for="email_from">From:</label> 
<input type="text" id="email_from" name="From" size="42" value=
"User Name<user@example.com>" /><br /> 
<label for="email_body">Message Body</label><br /> 
<textarea id="email_body" name="Body" rows="10" style="width: 100%"></textarea> 
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="$('email_form').submit(); bringForth(email_div,false);"/> 
</form>
```

It does what it is supposed to do, submits the body of the text is e-mailed to me.  The problem is who it comes from.  All I get is "User Name"  Then entire `"<user@example.com>"` is being stripped off.  Therefore, I am unable to reply.  Using `print_r($_REQUEST)` shows that the browser is stripping this off before posting.

I'm sure there is a simple reason for this, as well as a simple solution, but for the life of me I can't find it.  I've tried changing the enctype but to no avail.

Thanks in advance, 
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone, but as it turns out these aren't the issue.  The $header string needed a space between the "From:" and the POSTed string.  So, perhaps this was really an Apple Mail bug all along. I created a fixed header string, and it worked like a charm, and the only difference was that space.

--Dave

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your < and > symbols - "User Name **&lt;** user@example.com **&gt;**

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the angled brackets surrounding the email address: `%lt;user@examples.com%gt;`

Answer (score 0):

`<user@example.com>` is considered to be a tag. Try using `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlspecialchars_decode()` on server side